# Pass session VARIABLES to a subdomain, not just session ID

Tags: php, session, authentication

Since this was closed the first time even though it is NOT a duplicate of the thread I was directed to I shall ask again with a bit different wording.

My customers access my site at `www.sitename.com` to see products and stuff and whatever I offer on my website. If they have a website hosted by us, it has an online control panel available at `s1.sitename.com`. From there they can control their website settings.

I can pass my session id across the one server to the other and that works just fine. I want to be able to pass **set session variables** across to the other server as well.

I know I can store all the session info into a database and then read it from the other server and populate the information with that, BUT is there a way to send the session variables, **not just session id** across to the other server? If not then I will just use a database I guess.

Comment: You can store your sessions in the database

Comment: Yep, you can set the domain of the cookie, plus you could store them in memcache for servers.